# ORA 00920 In CASE with "OR" inside Trigger Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The syntax error seems to be in the `WHEN INSERTING OR UPDATING` (more specifically it underlines the `OR`), I don't understand why it doesn't work in a CASE condition but it works in a IF condition.

Its a `BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE` Trigger

Code portion of the issue:

```
SELECT 
    field 
INTO 
    my_var
FROM 
    my_table
WHERE 
    column1 = (CASE 
                        WHEN INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN 
                            :new.column2
                        ELSE --deleting
                            :old.column2
                        END);
```

What would be the solution?

Here is the rest of the trigger if anyone wants to test : https://pastebin.com/AJqGQyG8

Edit :
The issue seems to be that the WHEN condition needs an operator, so I tried using :

```
WHEN INSERTING = TRUE
```

But that just resulted in another error :

> ORA-00904: "TRUE": Invalid identified

Comment: I think you need two TRIGGERS, one for INSERT and one for UPDATE.

Comment: @TedFilippidis I think you meant one for INSERT/UPDATE and a different trigger for BEFORE DELETE

Comment: This was working when I had an IF/ELSE condition with two selects instead of the CASE, I was just trying to make the code more readable and ran into the issue.

Comment: Yes you are right I would split the trigger if you are looking for simplicity! Why you dislike the IF if its working? If it is not broken why try to fix, I always say :D

Comment: @TedFilippidis Well I just thought it was odd that the CASE expression didn't work with an OR and just wanted to find out why ^^

Comment: Does it work without the OR? You could just be redundant and add another "when" to the case for the other one.

Comment: @PatrickH it doesn't, it just hightlights the `THEN`

Comment: Splitting the OR to two WHEN is still not working?

Comment: @TedFilippidis No

Comment: Maybe it has to do with :old and :new then?! Just thinking out loud here :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that PL/SQL knows these boolean variables inside a trigger, but Oracle's SQL doesn't know BOOLEAN unfortunately.

One solution may be:

```
IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
  v_value := :new.column2;
ELSE
  v_value := :old.column2;
END IF;

...

SELECT field INTO my_var FROM my_table WHERE column1 = v_value;
```

Answer (score 3):

As Thorsten explained already, `inserting` and `updating` and `deleting` are predicates (expressions of BOOLEAN data type) which exist only in the PL/SQL code part of the trigger. They can't exist (or be used in any way) in a SQL statement, since Oracle SQL does not recognize/implement the BOOLEAN data type.

Moreover, `:new.<whatever>` and `:old.whatever` are also available only in the PL/SQL portion of your trigger; if you have embedded SQL, anything like `:new.<whatever>` is interpreted as a bind variable, not special in any way, and you will be prompted for a value (if you use an "advanced" front-end program) or you will simply get an error telling you that not all variables are bound.

Thorsten has already shown one way to do what you want to do. If you really need (want?) to use a `case` expression, you can do something like this:

Declare a variable (like `v_value` in Thorsten's answer) in the `DECLARE` section of the trigger. Assign the proper data type to it.

Then in the execution block write something like this, BEFORE the SQL statement:

```
v_value := case when inserting or updating then :new.column2 else :old.column2 end;
```

and then in the SQL statement compare to `v_value`, also as in Thorsten's answer.

Alternatively, you can assign the value to `v_value` in the `DECLARE` block, right as you declare it, in the usual (PL/SQL) way. In any case, the value must be assigned outside the SQL statement, not in it.